# Is the RAW image format supported by the image picker in iOS?

Tags: ios, image, ios5, import

It does not appear in the UTI Image Content Types. Also, if this is the case, is there a size limit on RAW image files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No RAW is not supported.  The size of the file (if lets say you brought it in via another method) could still be displayed and worked with if you processed it and converted it yourself to a UIImage to be displayed inside of a UIImageView or something.

As for size, the only real limitation is not the file size itself but the live processing size.  While not well documented, the overall size an app can use data wise is ~24 MB (or at least it used to be limited to this).  The file iteslf can be quite larger, but you will only be able to work with limited chunks at a time (if it is larger than the app size limit).

Also look here for the file types recognized by the UIImage object.  This is also the reason the UIImagePicker does not support it, as it uses UIImage objects within UIImageView objects.  Thus it can only support natively the types that UIImage objects support.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html